# get statement which triggered trigger. Or other identifiers

Tags: sql-server-2008, triggers

I have a table (items in stock) which gets updated from several applications.

All queries are supposed to also set a field 'src' with some audit information (user and form), but some queries are not doing that.

I intend to create a trigger on update, which checks if the 'src' field is changed.
I would like to rollback the update and fire an error if the 'src' is not set, but also to log the query, so I better can identify the offending application.

Is the actual query text available to the trigger?
Or any other identifier?
All connections to the database are done via scripts on webservers, with one of two logins, but from a handfull of servers, so the ip of the server might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

The connection information available is:

```
select * 
  from sys.dm_exec_connections as EC inner join
    sys.dm_exec_sessions as ES on ES.session_id = EC.session_id
  where EC.session_id = @@SPID
```

AFAIK you cannot get the triggering statement within a trigger.